# How to check Decimal Numeric with fixed whole and decimal value from String

Tags: java, regex

Please help me to get efficient way to find Numeric String.

```
String str ="-100000.000";
System.out.println(str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"));
```

it works perfectly but I want to accept Numeric Strings like this

```
String length must be maximum (10,3)--- Example 1234567890.999
String length must be minmum   (1)------0
Numeric String must be positive.

valid Numeric Strings(2.333    1878.12    787          989.0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your restrictions, you can use this regex:

```
"\\+?\\d{1,10}(\\.\\d{1,3})?"
```

You can look at the quantifiers section in [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Added the optionally leading `+`, as per your request in the comment.

Comment: Doesnt recognize positive numbers preceded by '+'

Comment: see the limiting repitition section [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) for further explenation of this answer.

Comment: @AdriánLópez: OP says nothing about leading `+` and has none in his examples. Also, you should mark your code as code in your answer.

Comment: True. He probably needs it anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your help..... if you can please add + as Adrian requested.Thanks guys....

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(str.matches("\\+?\\d{1,10}(\\.\\d{1,3})?"));
```